# How to write a script on the macbook to automatically login to the App Store?

Tags: applescript

How to write a script on the macbook to automatically log [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj0nL.jpg)in to the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "App Store"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    try
        click menu item "Sign In…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Store" of menu bar 1 of application process "App Store"
    end try
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    try
        select text field 1 of sheet 1 of window "App Store" of application process "App Store"
        delay 1
        keystroke "your password" -- enter your login password between the quotes
        key code 36
    end try
end tell
```